# When you are carrying an item, should you use WITH or ON(preposition)

Tags: prepositions, sentence-meaning

Let's say you are asking a caller if she is carrying a machine at the time. It goes like this:

> You:Do you have your machine **WITH/ON** you?(you assume that the machine is **beside** the caller)
>
> Caller: No, I don't. I left it in my house.

Should you use ON/WITH? And what if the machine is small, that it fits inside a pocket, should you use **in/with/on**

I believe this is tricky.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In situations like this, it is always appropriate to use **[with](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/with)**.

> Do you have your car with you?
>   Do you have your computer with you?
>   Do you have your pen with you?

If the item is small- a pen, a wallet or a phone that can be placed in a pocket, so that you are effectively wearing it, you can also use **on**. The [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/on), in the entry for POSSESSION, also includes items that are in a bag that you are carrying.

> Do you have a pen on you?

**[in](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/in)** means **inside**, so you can't really say **in you**. You can only really use it if you specify what it's inside:

> Do you have your phone in **your bag**?
>   Do you have your wallet in **your pocket**?

Because you have to specify where the object might be, this option is not particularly useful- except perhaps to make suggestions about something that the person has mislaid.